# Run a single job in parallel

Tags: talend

I need to know that how can we run a single job in parallel with different parameters in talend.

Comment: I would improve question <br> run same job at same time with different  parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is straightforward, but rather depends on what you want, and whether you are using free Talend or commercial.

As far as parameters go, make sure that your jobs are using context variables - this is the preferred way of passing parameters in.

As for running in parallel, there are a few options.

Talend's studio is a java code generator, so you can export your job (it's just java code) and run it wherever you want.  How you invoke it is up to you - schedule it, invoke it N times manually, your call.  Obviously, if your job touches shared resources then making it safe to run in parallel is up to you - the usual concurrency issues apply.

If you have the commercial product, then you can use the Talend admin centre (TAC).  The TAC allows you to schedule a job more than once with different contexts.  Or, if you want to keep the parallelization logic inside your job, then consider using the tParallelize component in one job to run another job N times.