# Running time / Memory issue while copying from excel to SQL tables using Talend

Tags: performance, talend

I am copying data from excel sheet to the SQL tables.
At this time it is around 2000 rows distributed across 18 tables.
Problem with my job is it is taking too much of time. It takes around 2.5 mins to do the job.

Other issue I am facing is with memory. I tried to copy around 250,000 rows and I couldn't run the job with basic settings. I have to increase Xms and Xmx allocation.

[image: Here is ,y job design]

How do I solve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

You should start your job with a tMSSQLConnection (I think that's the DBMS you're using) and then finish it with a tMSSQLCommit component and see if that helps at all as it could be that Talend is opening a large amount of connections to the database rather than pooling them.

Increasing the commit size will also help speed up bulk loads but obviously if anything fails to commit it will lose the entire commit.

As well as this, as long as you have no race conditions and don't care in what order tables are inserted to or updated then you could parallelise the whole job with either a tParallelize component or by enabling multi thread executions in the Extra tab under the Job window.

Sometimes the memory usage in the job can be improved by splitting the process down into separate jobs and linking them as child jobs in one large wrapper parent job with tRunJob components. This will also make the job more manageable.

Finally, there's a couple of options in the advanced settings of each database output component that allows you to increase the batch size (although this will increase the memory usage) and also to enable parallel connections which can greatly improve performance by utilising more database server cores.

Your memory issues are unlikely to be resolved short of re-engineering your job to only deal with smaller chunks of a data at a time and commit each part and then grab the next lot.

This could be done by using a tFilterRow component and only selecting the first x records (by some filter condition, if the data set has none you could always add one by first preprocessing everything to give every row a `Numeric.Sequence`), processing it and putting it in your table and then picking the next x records and so on.

Comment: I am using a tMSSql Connection but dont know how to use tMSSql commit. The order of the table matters as they are dependent on each other. I have edited my question and uploaded new screenshot. As you can see the property of my Profile table, I think I am opening up new connection for my each table. Am I right? Do I need to change this part? Re-engineering my job is not something I would like to do with this task.

Comment: The commit components are typically used in combination with the rollback components so you can better handle unexpected behaviour in your jobs otherwise Talend will auto commit things as per your database output components or at the end of the job. It looks like you are just using a single connection (as long as those database output components are using the connection component rather than opening their own connection). I'd like to know why the order of the tables being dealt with makes any difference because it just looks like a bulk ETL job to me.

Comment: Later on in my job I am doing a databse lookup. i.e. Table will copy some of the columns from excel sheet and some of the columns from already filled up tables. It is to satisfy foreign key constraints. Those columns would be database generated key columns.

Comment: So parallelise the initial load? You should also still be able to set the database output components to use parallel connections which is thread safe.

Comment: Will using single tMap for all the tables help?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062165/run-a-single-job-in-parallel) for how to parallelise jobs in Talend. If you're using the Open Studio you will have to split your job in to the parts you wish to run in parallel as otherwise you have no control over what bits get run in parallel. I'd definitely attempt to use the parallel connections to the database though.

Comment: What do you mean by parallel connections to the database?

Comment: My answer talks about how to enable multi threaded connections to the database. It may or may not be available in the Open Studio though.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Singe Insert Query" in the MSSQL output. Make sure you're using the correct batch size.
Batch should should be LESS OR EQUAL to:  `2000 / column count`. This could speed up the load speed.

However I'm not sure about the memory errors. I think talend tries to read the excel inputs into memory as a whole, thus for bigger the excel files you need more memory.

Comment: 2000 is the total number of rows across 18 tables. It ranges from 2 to 250. How do I calculate maximum batch size allowed?

Comment: I have tried this approach but can't see any major difference in running time.

Comment: what is the row/sec you get? without this technique we only had 50-300 row/sec. With this we could achieve 5-7k row/sec.

Comment: My Row/Sec is dependent on the number of records in excel sheet.  For the excel sheet of 10 rows -> 1.25 row/sec, 500 rows -> 50 rows /sec. It gets increasing as the number of rows in excel sheet increases. I have had up to 4000 rows/sec. I have observe that it is taking time (around 5-6 seconds) in opening up the excel sheet. I have 17 tables to copy data to, so it takes atleast 17*6 = 100 seconds in just opening up the excel sheets each time I run a job.

Comment: If you're seeing such a delay on opening the Excel sheets your only real solution is to parallelise it out or just take it as it is. If performance really is that important to you then you'll have to rework your job in to two jobs and enable multi threading on the first job containing the initial load.

Comment: The problem was with the Excel sheet. It had hidden sheets and a sheet with buttons which were making its size very large. I have removed them and it now works real fast.